# Pyspark MapReduce Object List

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I have an object list defined as:

```
class AD:
    def __init__(self, name=None, impressions=0):
        self.name = name
        self.impressions= impressions
```

Now, is there a way to use the map reduce method to get an updated AD list grouping by the name, with the summation of impressions. For example:

```
adList = []

ad1 = AD("BlackFriday",29)
ad2 = AD("BlackFriday",33)
ad3 = AD("CyberMonday",35)

adList .append(a1)
adList .append(a2)
adList .append(a3)
```

I know i don't have to use the map reduce function to get my result. By if i were to use map reduce, how do i get the following result:

```
newList[0].name = "BlackFriday"
newList[0].impressions = 62

newList[1].name = "CyberMonday"
newList[1].impressions = 35
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @zero323 this is Spark related ?

Comment: @eliasah My question is the same :) I've corrected the indentation and added Python tag just to make it look a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

**The following code is untested as I dont have any environment available**

Your inputs:

```
ad1 = AD("BlackFriday",29)
ad2 = AD("BlackFriday",33)
ad3 = AD("CyberMonday",35)
```

To be able to use `map` + `reduce`, you need some RDD (for this, you can use `parallelize`)

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(list((ad1, ad2, ad3)))
```

Then you `map` the rdds to a tuple of `(name, impressions)` so that you can reduce after by key

```
rddReduced = rdd.map(lambda a: (a.name, a.impressions)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x + y)
```

Then you `map` back to an AD object and call `collect` to get the result as a list

```
adList = rddReduced.map(lambda (n,i): AD(n,i)).collect()
```

Comment: I don't know how you understood the question, but cheers ! I have corrected the rdd creation code. I'm still not sure about your last code line so far. Can you check that please @zero323 ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The way i understood the requirement is that he wants at the end a list of ADs with the sum of impressions by key. i.e. `AD(BlackFriday, 29 +33 )`